# Ubuntu installation interface not responding

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, uefi

I just bought a new HP Pavilion 15 with Windows 10 Home already installed. I wanted to install a dual boot with the latest Ubuntu OS (Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS). I disable the Secure Boot and the Fast Boot options. I put Ubuntu on my USB key with Rufus (FAT32, on GPT/UEFI partition) and ran my laptop from it. Ubuntu runs, and then, after more or less 15 seconds, I can't click on anything. I still can see my mouse move but the UI is not responding... I already tried several times but it is always the same problem.

Does anyone have ever run into this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you meet ubuntu's minimum installation requirements:

2 GHz dual core processor or better

2 GB system memory

25 GB of free hard drive space

Comment: I have this specs : https://support.hp.com/za-en/document/c06160668 . I think it is largely enough

Comment: Idk how accurate the answer on this forum is but can confirm that 4.15.0-24-generic x86_64 kernel was a little buggy for me too and the system freezed for few seconds then came back to being normal, not sure if that's the case tho, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2396635